# Loop in pgfplots doesn't work

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

I'm trying to do a loop in `pgfplots` to draw a bunch of rectangles under a curve, but it doesn't work.  This is my code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[   
    width=160pt,compat=1.5.1,grid style={ultra thin},  
    x tick label style={font=\tiny},y tick label style={font=\tiny},  
    scale only axis,grid=major,axis lines=middle,  
    xlabel={$x$},  
    ylabel={$y$},  
    xmin=-0.13,  
    xmax=1.6,  
    domain=-0.25:2,  
    ymin=-0.3,  
    ymax=3.3,  
    xtick={0,0.25,...,1.5}, xticklabels={,,0.5,,1,,1.5},  
    ytick={0,0.5,...,3},  
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.05)},anchor=north,nodes={right}},  
    extra tick style={tickwidth=2pt},  
        extra x ticks={1.1},  
       extra x tick labels={$ 1.1 $},  
]  

\addplot [red,thick,samples=200] { sin(deg(x^2)) };  
\addlegendentry{$ g(x)=\sin\left(x^2\right) $}

\foreach \n [evaluate={\y=sin(deg((\n+0.05)^2))}] in {0,0.05,...,1}  
\draw (axis cs: \n, 0) rectangle (axis cs: \n+0.05, \y);  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please make a complete example.

Comment: What happens when you compile jfbu's code below?

Comment: the rectangles right side is drawn correctly however the left leg is missing. Instead the top of the rectangles goes all the way to the y-axis its really strange :/

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why your code does not compile, not knowing enough (or rather not knowing anything) about `tikz` and `pgfplots`. But this variant works

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-0.1:1.1]
\begin{axis}[   
    width=160pt,compat=1.5.1,grid style={ultra thin},  
    x tick label style={font=\tiny},y tick label style={font=\tiny},  
    scale only axis,grid=major,axis lines=middle,  
    xlabel={$x$},  
    ylabel={$y$},  
    xmin=-0.13,  
    xmax=1.6,  
    domain=-0.25:2,  
    ymin=-0.3,  
    ymax=3.3,  
    xtick={0,0.25,...,1.5}, xticklabels={,,0.5,,1,,1.5},  
    ytick={0,0.5,...,3},  
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.05)},anchor=north,nodes={right}},  
    extra tick style={tickwidth=2pt},  
        extra x ticks={1.1},  
       extra x tick labels={$ 1.1 $},  
]  

\addplot [red,thick,samples=200] { sin(deg(x^2)) };  
\addlegendentry{$ g(x)=\sin\left(x^2\right) $}

  \foreach \n [evaluate={\y=sin(deg((\n+0.05)^2))}] in {0,0.05,...,1}
    {%
    \edef\x {\noexpand \draw (axis cs: \n, 0) rectangle (axis cs: \n+0.05, \y)}%
    \x;
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots with foreach]

Comment: its really weird because when I take your exact code and put it into my Texstudio it doesnt compile like yours :(

Comment: very strange.. but does it compile at all, or is there some error? try perhaps with `\documentclass{article}` or without `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}`, is your installation up to date?